# What redirect URL to specify for a thick Yammer client

Tags: jmeter, yammer

I would like to be able to post from my JMeter script to my Yammer group whenever i start or stop my test. As i understand the only way to do this is to create an app in Yammer (or is that not correct?). The app registration form requires a redirect URL as I am going to post from JMeter what should i specify as the redirect URL?

I am currently doing this successfully with HipChat but would also like to post to Yammer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you should go with *https://www.yammer.com*

as the yammer guide states:

[image]

I haven't done it myself, though.

Hope it does the trick.

Comment: You are correct, this is what the documentation suggests i use but when i make a call to authenticate a user i need to provide this redirect url because the token would be return to that redirect URL and using yammer.com breaks what i want to do.